# Stop generation tables and fieldset tag in output of Check box / Radio button Group control

Tags: xpages

When using a checkbox group XPage generates `fieldset` and `table` tags around it. Is there a way to *not* generate that? For e.g. if my XPage source looks like this -

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup" disableTheme="true" value="#{document1.CheckboxGroup}">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:new Array("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3");}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Then my generated code is

```
<fieldset id="view:_id1:checkBoxGroup">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><input name="view:_id1:checkBoxGroup" value="Option 1" type="checkbox"> Option 1</input></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><input name="view:_id1:checkBoxGroup" value="Option 2" type="checkbox"> Option 2</input></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><input name="view:_id1:checkBoxGroup" value="Option 3" type="checkbox"> Option 3</input></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

That's a lot of code for three checkboxes. And it messes up my CSS as putting any CSS for `table` tag puts it on the checkbox group also. The also goes for radio button group. I tried setting `disableTheme` property to `true` but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fundamentally change the structure of the HTML representation of a component, you can use the Extensibility API to [create an alternate renderer](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Basic_UI_Control_for_XPages#Creating+the+control+renderer). This allows you full control over what markup is sent to the browser for a specific component instance without changing how any other components are rendered. Register the renderer with the same `component-family` as the default renderer (`javax.faces.SelectMany`), but assign it a custom `renderer-type`; if you then assign that custom value to the `rendererType` property of a specific checkbox group, Domino will use your custom renderer class to emit the HTML instead of the default renderer class.

Comment: I just went through the wiki you posted. So if I create custom renderer class and register it the `faces-config.xml` then I can use that class in `rendererType` property. Right? Please bear with me as I am new to extensiblility API.

Comment: Correct. For instance, if in the faces-config you specify a custom renderer-type of "cssFriendlyCheckboxGroup", then on your XPage, set that same value in the rendererType attribute of your component, and it will use your Java class instead of the native one.

Comment: Thanks Tim I was able to write my own output but to get options I writing this inside `encodeBegin` method `XspSelectManyCheckbox chk = (XspSelectManyCheckbox)component;List l = chk.getChildren();for (int i=0 ; i<l.size() ; i++) {UISelectItemsEx uisie = (UISelectItemsEx)l.get(i);javax.faces.model.SelectItem[] si = (javax.faces.model.SelectItem[])uisie.getValue();for (int k=0 ; k<si.length ; k++) {System.out.println(si[k].getValue());}}`. Apologies for formatting, it works but is this the correct way? If not then is there a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `xp:radio` control instead of the `xp:radioGroup` control and then group several radio buttons using the `groupName` property. Radio buttons rendered from xp:radio are not surrounded with fieldset and table.

Comment: Thanks Per, another option for me if extensibility API doesn't work out.