# comboBox generates a table instead of span in readmode web

Tags: xpages

When viewing a Xpage on the web containing a table with a comboBox in a column the html generated by Domino creates a table for the combobox but a span for other components *(tested currently on textFields and computedFields)*.
This is then rendered with a pixel of vertical alignment difference that annoys me.
How can I overcome this?

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table id="view:_id1:_id2:_id3:legend1:callbackFieldControlSet:CounterpartyName">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    AVANZA SWEDEN
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="view:_id1:_id2:_id3:legend1:callbackFieldControlSet:CounterpartyShort">AVANZA SWEDEN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In edit mode the difference is still there but the generated html of the combobox is not a table but a select and then I can control it using css.
See picture below.

**Example read mode**
[image: example read mode]

**Example edit mode (css edited):**
[image: example edit mode]

```
<xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label
                    value="Counterparty name:"
                    id="counterpartyName_Label1"
                    for="CounterpartyName"
                >
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox
                    id="CounterpartyName"
                    value="#{document1.CounterpartyName}"
                    required="true"
                >
                </xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label
                    value="Counterparty short:"
                    id="counterpartyShort_Label1"
                    for="CounterpartyShort"
                >
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText
                    value="#{document1.CounterpartyShort}"
                    id="CounterpartyShort"
                    required="true"
                    styleClass="xspInputFieldEditBox"
                >
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label
                    value="Bic Code:"
                    id="bicCode_Label1"
                    for="BicCode"
                >
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText
                    value="#{document1.BicCode}"
                    id="BicCode"
                    styleClass="xspInputFieldEditBox"
                >
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
```

Comment: Anyone figured out why it's rendered as table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

problem is that the inner table has its own borders (as always: one for the table itself and one for the td) which need to be collapsed. Just create some CSS to handle this:

1. give your outer table its own style-class e.g. "myOuterTable"
2. your css would then address any table inside ".myOuterTable", like this:

   table.myOuterTable table {border-collapse: collapse;}

This works fine in both edit and read mode because only in read mode you have that extra "inner" table; in edit mode, there's nothing to be collapsed...

works even in IE, btw...

Hope it works for you

Comment: Works great, thx.  I think IBM should render it differently though

Comment: totally agree; on the other hand we cannot rule out the possibility they had a reason for solving it this way...

Comment: In my case the shown value was off to the right too. I had to add also this `table.myOuterTable td {padding: 0;}`.

Answer (score 16):

*I see you have accepted an answer but I am proposing an alternate solution which simply eliminates the generated HTML. I realize that this can be a tedious solution :)*

I had a similar problem with [XPages generating tables for checkbox group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973812/stop-generation-tables-and-fieldset-tag-in-output-of-check-box-radio-button-gr). Tim Tripcony suggested me to [create a custom renderer](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Basic_UI_Control_for_XPages#Creating+the+control+renderer) to modify the output of the control. Its a little tricky at first but once you get a hang of it it does a pretty good job. In your case of read-only fields, it would be more simple :)

**1. Create a custom renderer**

Here I create a custom renderer Java class called `pkg.MyRenderer`. You can create this Java file in "Code > Java". Here I just output the selected value of the combo box and nothing else.

```
package pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectOne;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;

public class MyRenderer extends Renderer {
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        UISelectOne obj = (UISelectOne)component;
        Writer writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.write(obj.getValue().toString());
    }

    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    }
}
```

**2. Register your custom renderer**

Now in the Package Explorer go to "YourDatabase.nsf > WebContent > WEB-INF > **faces-config.xml**". There you need to register your custom renderer. You just need to make sure the `component-family` is same as the one to which the combo box belongs to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
            <renderer-type>pkg.MyRendererType</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>pkg.MyRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

**3. Assign your custom renderer to control**

As you want the custom renderer to be active only when it is in reading only mode you check for it and then set the `rendererType` of control as the `renderer-type` defined in `faces-config.xml` i.e. `pkg.MyRendererType`.

Here I check if the control `comboBox1` is in read-only mode, if yes then use `pkg.MyRendererType` else use the control's renderer.

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" .....>
    <xp:this.rendererType><![CDATA[${javascript:var cb:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu = getComponent("comboBox1");
cb.isReadonly() ? "pkg.MyRendererType" : cb.getRendererType();}]]></xp:this.rendererType>
.....
.....
.....
</xp:comboBox>
```

When you run this with control on read-only mode then only the value of combo box is displayed and nothing else (no tables, *yay!*). And when the control is not in read-only mode then a drop-down list is shown as before.

Comment: Thx, I'll keep this in mind. For simplicity I stick with the CSS solution

Comment: @Naveen: that's a great example; I've been curious how to use custom  renderers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

3 possible actions (in depending complexity) :

- write your own drop down component
- add  a text field.  Use the visible property to show/hide only one based on read/edit mode
- use css and padding (can take negative values) to move one pixel

Comment: agree that #1 or #2 could be the "proper" solutions while my approach has some taste of css hack to it. Never know whether that's good or bad in the long run.

Comment: One more addition to your list - you could define your own custom renderer.

Comment: You can't have negative padding, only negative margins. But that's was perhaps what stwissel meant to say.

Comment: I always mix up margin and padding, thx for pointing it out @jBoive

Answer (score 1):

This code will fix all comboboxes on the page with dojo, run onClientLoad:

```
if("#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}" == "false"){
    // Search for all nested tables with ids
    dojo.query('table td table[id]').forEach(function(node) {
        var value = '';

        // Locate the first table cell, which contains the value
        dojo.query('td:first-child', node).forEach(function(innerNode) {
            value = innerNode.innerHTML;
        });

        // Replace the table with only the value (or a blank)
        node.outerHTML = value;
    });
}
```

Notes:

- Update the name of the document in line 1 to match the name of the document on your page.
- This code assumes that your combobox is already nested in a table cell. If that's not the case, you can refine the selector in line 3.
- If you run into conflicts with this affecting other tables in your page, you may need to refine the selector in line 3.