# Xpages combobox size bigger then inputText size

Tags: css, combobox, xpages

I have a table with inputTexts and comboBoxes within it. In edit mode is all working fine, but in read mode, the text within the comboBoxes seem to have padding, but they don't. I checked with Chrome and it seem that the combobox has, by default, another element inside it, a table which contains the text.

**Question:** How can I remove that table inside the combobox in order for the elements to align better, withouth having to put `margin-left` and `margin-top` to the combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom renderers (which is the most elegant way but also advanced).

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=remove-table-tag-for-listboxes-in-read-mode-for-all-instances-in-one-go

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rendered property. Show **comboBox** only if document is in editmode

```
rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}"
```

and add a **computed field** which shows the value as plain text with the rendered property

```
rendered="#{javascript:!document1.isEditable()}"
```

As an alternative, you can use Brad Balassaitis' solution from his [blog](http://xcellerant.net/2013/07/24/xpages-tip-fixing-the-display-of-comboboxes-in-read-mode/). He deletes nested tables  onClientLoad.

Or, you work with [css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15831431/2065611).